# Cómo puedo recorrer este tipo de array

Tags: php

Tengo este array que me devuelve los datos de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para sacar los datos, lo hago asi:

```
$ofertasCiudades[0]['ofertas'][1]['titulo']
```

Donde [0] es un ID del array y [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T66Uy.png) también, necesito recorrerlo completo para extraer todos su datos y pintarlos en una vista.

No se me ocurre como recorrerlo, por mas que he buscado, no veo la manera, si alguien me puede dar una pista se lo agradezco llevo en esto varios días y no veo como recorrerlo, entiendo y si no corregidme que es un Array multi dimensional, si no es así corregidme.

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste con un doble `foreach`?

Comment: Si intente con doble `@foreach` pero no soy capaz-

Comment: Hola @marcoa debes ofrecer algo más de información para poder ofrecerte ayuda efectiva. En lo posible no usar imágenes y publicar el código que usas para obtener los resultados que muestras. Eventualmente, sería bueno que incluyas qué parámetros espera tu vista para preparar la salida.

Comment: Hola @quevedo, en lo sucesivo tomo en cuenta cada una de tus indicaciones, muchas gracias por la aclaración. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derivas poder recorrerlo de la siguiente forma:

```php
foreach($ofertasCiudades as $ofertaCiudad){
   echo $ofertaCiudad['id'];
   echo $ofertaCiudad['city'];
   echo $ofertaCiudad['slug'];
   foreach($ofertaCiudad['ofertas'] as $oferta){
      echo $oferta['id']
      echo $oferta['titulo']
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, y yo juraría haberlo intentado de esta manera, pero no me salia. Mil gracias a los dos.