# Como discriminar o no imprimir un valor de un array, dentro de un foreach doble

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

En una vista de Laravel 6, recibo un array, el cual puedo recorrer con 2 `foreachs`, gracias a la ayuda de varios miembros, este es el enlace, por si alguien lo necesita, [Cómo puedo recorrer este tipo de array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329153/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-recorrer-este-tipo-de-array).

Tengo 2 modelos con relación, muchos a muchos, de la siguiente manera.

**Modelo :City**

```
    class City extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'citys';


    // Relacion uno a muchos
        public function populations(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Population');
    }

    //Relacion Muchos a Muchos
        public function ofertas(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Oferta');
        }
}
```

**Modelo: Oferta**

```
class Oferta extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ofertas';

    //Relacion Muchos a Muchos
    public function citys(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\City');
    }
}
```

**En el controlador tengo:**

```
$ciudadesConOfertas = City::where ('id' ,'=', $id)->with('ofertas')->get();
```

**En la vista poblaciones_butano, lo recojo y recorro de la siguiente manera:**

```
@foreach( $ciudadesConOfertas as $ciudadesConOferta)
                            <p></p>
         @foreach($ciudadesConOferta['ofertas'] as $oferta)

/*Aqui quiero discriminar o elegir, si el campo-vector titulo contiene la palabra butano */

           @if ( ($oferta['titulo'])->is ('*-butano*') )
              <li> {!!$oferta['descri1']!!}{!!$oferta['descri2']!!}}</li>
                 <p>Precio: {{$oferta['precio']}}</p>

           @endif


        @endforeach
        @endforeach
```

En la variable `$oferta['titulo']`, viene la siguiente información:

> revision-de-gas-butano
>   revision-de-gas-propano

El `@if ( ($oferta['titulo'])->is ('*-butano*') )`, ¿Como se hace esta comparación? Aqui me arroja el error ***"Call to a member function is() on string (View: C:\laragon\www\revisiones\resources\views\poblaciones.blade.php)"***

Si utilizo la formula `@if ( request()->is ('*-propano*'))` y la URL lleva esa cadena, me funciona perfecto.

¿Como puedo hacer esa comparación, o bien como puedo discriminar en función, de si trae un texto o cadena un array?

Saludos

Comment: Puedes hacer un where con un distinto, con el operador "<>"

Comment: Hola lo he intentado, y me da un error, mi pongo lo que intente.             `$ciudadesConOfertas = City::where ('id' ,'=', $id)
                ->join ('ofertas','ofertas.titulo', 'like', '%propano%')
  
                ->with('ofertas')->get();`, y me da el siguiente error, **Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `citys` inner join `ofertas` on `ofertas`.`titulo` like `%propano%` where `id` = 1)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que la función/método que estás buscando es `Str::is()`:

```
@if ( \Illuminate\Support\Str::is('*-butano*', $oferta['titulo']) )
```

Revisa su documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-str-is

---

No estoy muy seguro de qué `is()` te está tomando cuando lo aplicas de esa manera (como lo muestras en la pregunta), pero seguramente debe aplicarse en un objeto, como es el caso de Request.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, me ha valido perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

También se puede hacer con esta linea de código

```
@if ( strpos($oferta['titulo'], 'butano') !== false )
```

He utilizado la función, `strpos()`, esta, encuentra la posición de la primera aparición de una cadena dentro de otra cadena, distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, ojo, le pregunto que si es diferente a falso, `!== false` osea que contiene esa cadena, que realice lo que yo le pida, así puedo discriminar en un foreach.

[strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php)

Comment: Considera explicar tu aporte, pues las respuestas que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad